# Is this bike fork misaligned?

Tags: fork, cruiser

Just received the delivery of a new Ken 26" Bayside bike, and the first thing to do was put up the front wheel but it seems like the forks are misaligned (although there is no apparent damage in shipping).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Am I correct, or is there a technical detail about assembly that I am missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those forks are badly deformed.  Interesting, I looked up the bikes and the first Google hit (https://www.bikeride.com/womens-kent-bayside-womens/) has the first reason not to buy
"Many users reported the Bayside's fork and wheels were damaged....".

I suggest you do not ride the bike and start the returns/warranty claims process. Apart from the obvious problems of handling and safety, it looks like the dropouts are so far out of alignment I would be concerned about breaking the front axle.

Comment: agree completely. To the OP: stop working on the bike. Repackage it. Return it. Get a refund.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, I will open an issue with the manufacturer, as I bought it directly from kent.bike

Comment: If the manufacturer offers to send in a replacement fork is it easy to replace?

Comment: @WaqasIlyas For an experienced mechanic, yes. If you're not and experience bike mechanic, I recommend you take it to one.